# Jmeter-file compare

Tags: file, jmeter, compare

I am new to jmeter & I am looking for an option to compare two files using Jmeter. Both the files are generated using `Save Response to file` in jmeter. Also both files contain response to a jdbc request, with 100s of values across multiple columns & rows. I am using `__FileToString()` function in my response assertion to compare the two files. But this fails if my file has data with some special chars. Any tips how could I handle this ? OR any other ways to compare two Jmeter created files ? I would also want to know the records that are different in both files.
I know files could be compared using a lot of other tools, but I would really want to do this using Jmeter please. Thank you!

Comment: You should edit to add the tag 'jmeter' so users following the tag will see your post

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](http://www.groovy-lang.org/). For example this code allows comparison of two text files:

```
def file1 = new File('/path/to/file1')
def file2 = new File('/path/to/file2')

def file1Lines = file1.readLines('UTF-8')
def file2Lines = file2.readLines('UTF-8')

if (file1Lines.size() != file2Lines.size()) {
   SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
   SampleResult.setResponseMessage('Files size is different, omitting line-by-line compare')
} else {
   def differences = new StringBuilder()

   file1Lines.eachWithIndex { String file1Line, int number ->
       String file2Line = file2Lines.get(number)
       if (!file1Line.equals(file2Line)) {
           differences.append('Difference # ').append(number).append('. Expected: ')
                   .append(file1Line).append('. Actual: ' + file2Line)
           differences.append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
       }
   }

   if (differences.toString().length() > 0) {
       SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
       SampleResult.setResponseMessage(differences.toString())
   }
}
```

In case of any differences, the sampler will fail and you will see the information about deltas in the "Response Message" section:

[image: Groovy compare 2 files]

Not that this will not necessary work for all types of files, for example, binary files.

References:

- [Groovy: reading files](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#_reading_files)
- [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class JavaDoc
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you Dmitri for your response but this code is giving below error - groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult.setSussessful() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Boolean) values: [false]
Possible solutions: setSuccessful(boolean). Tried finding the cause but couldnt get anything. Can you help ? Thanks!