# Is it possible to validate a downloaded file in Jmeter?

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

I have a REST service that I'm currently testing in J-Meter. I have a number of endpoints that I'm currently testing, they do the following:

1. Allow the upload of files to the service
2. Return a list of available files
3. Allow the download of files from the list

I have tests in J-Meter that test all this functionality, and it works well. But I'm wondering if it's possible to verify that the files I uploaded are exactly the same as the files I've downloaded in J-Meter? 
Is this possible? Maybe by hashing both files and comparing perhaps?

Comment: is that helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101895/jmeter-file-compare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can find `Save response as MD5 hash` option at the "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler.

   [image: JMeter save as md5]

   When this option is checked JMeter will return the response in form of [MD5 Checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)
2. In order to validate the response add [MD5Hex Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MD5Hex_Assertion). You can either put pre-calculated MD5 Hash of the required file there or use [__MD5() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#MD5supfont-color-gray-size-1-since-0-4-2-font-sup) in combination with [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) in order to calculate MD5 Hash of the source file "on-the-fly" like:

   ```
   ${__MD5(${__FileToString(/path/to/source/file.json,,)},)}
   ```

   [image: JMeter MD5 assertion]

   You can install MD5 Function plugin as a part of [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions) bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/).

For more information on this and other JMeter assertions check out [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.